# How to connect a mass to a telescopic piston?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, mass

I'd like to ask for your help again, to study my telescopic piston on OPenModelica.
In particular, to simulate the action of the mass that will come to the end of my piston.
To do this, I first connected my 3 cylinders to the same mass (input), but if I'm not mistaken, I can't connect 3 inputs to the same mass.
Because I get this error: "[2] 14:30:47 Traduction Erreur
Internal error Selection of DummyDerivatives failed due to negative system rank of -2!
There are 3 unassigned equations and 1 potential states.

[3] 14:30:47 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.selectDummyDerivatives2new failed!

[4] 14:30:47 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.processComps4New failed!

[5] 14:30:47 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.dynamicStateSelectionWork failed!"
Then I thought of measuring the force using sensors on my 3 cylinders, but I can't get to the end:[image]
Finally, I wrote a program as follows
to mean that when the first cylinder reaches its limit stop, it no longer acts on the mass (this is the case for the second and third cylinders).

```
if BleuStop.flange_b>0.18 then
     connect(forceSensor.flange_b, mass.flange_a) ; 
  elseif NoirStop.flange_b>0.36 then
     connect(forceSensor1.flange_b, mass.flange_a)   ;
  else
     connect(forceSensor2.flange_b, mass.flange_a);
  end if;
```

But I get another error « Cannot resolve type of expression BleuStop.flange_b > (0.18). The operands have types Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.Flange_b, Real in component <NO_COMPONENT>. »
Can you please help me?

Comment: From what I understand, in a "telecopic piston" one cylinder should move the next piston etc. and the mass is only connected to the last one. From a Modelica point of view, you should have something like a "support flange" as in Modelica.Magnetic.FluxTubes.Shapes.Force.HollowCylinderAxialFlux where the next piston is connected. In total you should have three in series with the last one having the mass attached.
This would require a new piston model though as there is nothing like this in the Modelica Standard Library (MSL). Probably you could find one outside the MSL...

Comment: Regarding your issues: You cannot simply switch connections during simulation as this would require the model to change its structure...

Comment: @Markus A.
Yes, that's right, but if I'm not mistaken, my 2 previous cylinders also have an impact on the mass. How can I represent this? 
Because if I put the mass on the last piston, I'm neglecting the impact of the others...

Comment: Yes they have an influence. But you need to connect the mass to the flanges of all cylinders at the same time (given you otherwise have a structure-variable system, see answer by marco). Doing this, you will also set the length of the cylinders equal and I don't think this is what you want.
What you need is a cylinder with flanges on both sides. You could modify the one from the MSL or use e.g. the one from https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/OpenHydraulics/releases/tag/v2.0.0 (OpenHydraulics.Components.Cylinders.DoubleActingCylinder).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I only have access to the Open Source software, so I can't open the files I can download via your link...

Comment: Did you try to download the source code, unzip the file and open `OpenHydraulics-2.0.0.zip\OpenHydraulics-2.0.0\OpenHydraulics\package.mo` with OpenModelica? This should be possible...

Comment: I am not sure, I got this error "[C:/Users/emma/Downloads/OpenHydraulics-2.0.0/OpenHydraulics-2.0.0/OpenHydraulics/Components/package.mo: 2:1-9:15]: Expected the package to have within ; but got within OpenHydraulics;."

Comment: Try to open `C:/Users/emma/Downloads/OpenHydraulics-2.0.0/OpenHydraulics-2.0.0/OpenHydraulics/package.mo` (without "Components" in the path). You should always use the top-level package.mo.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple issues.

### 1. Illegal if conditions

The error message

> The operands have types Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.Flange_b, Real in component <NO_COMPONENT>

tries to tell you, that `BleuStop.flange_b>0.18` does not work, as you compare a connector with a scalar. `flange_b` contains the two variables `s` and `f`, so you must use `BleuStop.flange_b.s` or `BleuStop.flange_b.f` instead.

### 2. No structural variability in Modelica

If you fix your if conditions the model will still not work. The structure of a Modelica models cannot change during the simulation. Therefore it is not possible to change connections dynamically.

### 3. Connecting multiple flanges

Regarding

> I can't connect 3 inputs to the same mass.

If you connect to a mass, you don't use inputs, you have connectors named flanges. This is an important point, as inputs also exist in Modelica (as keyword and as specialized, causal connector).

Connecting multiple components to the flange of a mass does work in general, but you have to keep in mind that the position of all connected flanges is set equal.
With the connections in your screenshot you generate the following equations by connecting the stop models to the mass (neglecting the sensors, which have no physical meaning):

```
mass1.flange_l.s = BlueStop.flange_r.s
mass1.flange_l.s = NoirStop.flange_r.s
mass1.flange_l.s = RogueStop.flange_r.s
```

The cylinders are rigidly connected to the stop models, which have a fixed length `L` (assuming you are using `Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.MassWithStopAndFriction`). Consequently, the position of the right flange of all three cylinders is set equal. This is probably the reason that your initial attempt did not work and you came to the wrong conclusion that multiple connections to the same flange are not possible.